# Cox model with frailty (partial loglikelihood and df)

Tags: survival, cox-model, degrees-of-freedom, likelihood, frailty

I am fitting a Cox propotional hazard model with a frailty term using the `survival` package in `R`. When I remove a fixed efect, I am surprised that both the partial loglikelihood and the number of degress of freedom increase, as I would expect both of them to decrease in a model with fewer parameters. Would any one have an explanation for this?

Here is an example :

```
library(survival)
data(kidney)
m1 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + disease + frailty(id), data = kidney)
m2 <- coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + frailty(id), data = kidney, control=coxph.control(iter.max=100))
logLik(m1)
'log Lik.' -179.0793 (df=5.000015)
logLik(m2)
'log Lik.' -164.5238 (df=14.14458)
```

Comment: control=coxph.control(iter.max=100) is present in m2 and not m1, could you explain why this difference exists?

Comment: Thanks. Unfortunately, it does not (without this argument, the number of iterations by default is just too low for the second model to converge)